# Ruby factory method returns a NoMethodError when it's called. What happened?

Tags: ruby, methods, factory

I'm trying to integrate a factory method into this imperial-to-metric converter. I can make it work independently, but when it's iterated through a hash of ingredients it brings up a `NoMethodError`. What did I do wrong?

I've run independent instance variables through the factory without issue:

```
@item = "cups"
@number = 89.2
Gramulator.for(@number, @item) # => 828.0300000000001
```

I've confirmed that it works properly with inputs. I've even run it with `@dough.unit` and `@dough.amount` successfully:

```
Gramulator for(@dough.amount, @dough.unit) # => 828.0300000000001
```

But when I point it through the iteration method itself, `@dough.gramulate` doesn't work.

```
class Unit
  def initialize(amount)
    @amount = amount
  end

  def calculate
    @amount.to_f
  end
end

class Cup < Unit
  def calculate
    (super * 236.58)
  end
end

class Recipe
  attr_accessor :amount
  attr_reader   :name, :unit

  def initialize(ingredient_hash)
    @ingredient_hash = ingredient_hash
  end

  def gramulate
    puts "CONVERTED TO GRAMS:"
    @ingredient_hash.each do |name, quantity|
      quantity_array = quantity.split

      @name    =  name
      @amount  =  quantity_array[0].to_f
      @unit    =  quantity_array[1]

      Gramulator.for(@amount, @unit)
      puts "#{@name}: #{@amount} grams"
    end
  end
end

module Gramulator

  @units = {
    "cups"   => Cup
    # <other measurements>
  }

  def self.for(unit, amount)
    (@units[unit]).new(amount).calculate
  end
end

@dough = Recipe.new({
  bread_flour: "3.5 cups"
  # <other ingredients>
})
```

Expected result:

```
CONVERTED TO GRAMS:
bread_flour: 828.0300000000001 grams
```

Actual result:

```
CONVERTED TO GRAMS:
NoMethodError: undefined method 'new' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: I should note that iterations work fine by commenting out the factory and including the line
`puts "#{@name}: #{@amount} #{@unit}"`

Comment: `@units[unit]` returns nil

Comment: @KimmoLehto, thank you for your response. Would you please elaborate a bit? Is it a naming convention? It doesn't return nil when I supply variables directly to `unit` and `amount` in the method.

Comment: You need to inspect what's in there and what you're trying to access from it. `bread_flour: 3.5 cups,` looks wrong.

Comment: It's probably too convoluted, but I was afraid I couldn't duplicate the issue outside of context. I've stripped off `bread_flour` as `@name` in the hash, leaving `quantity`. That gets `.split` into [0] `@amount` (`3.5`) and [1] `@unit` (`"cups"`).

Comment: Edited: addressed the typo you mention. It's unfortunately not a relevant in the source code.

Comment: Yeah the comma isn't relevant, but `3.5 cups` should give a syntax error.

Comment: So sorry, edited again.

Comment: Just curious...Which is the design idea behind using a Module for the Gramulator instead of a class? I don't see it included anywhere

Comment: @microspino, a mentor told me to separate 'doers' and 'things' that way. I agree it's not really helpful here.

Comment: The error message should tell you which line the problem is on. Unfortunately, you don't tell us this information. Also, please make sure that you construct a [mcve]. In particular, it seems that your example is not really minimal, I guess it would be possible to demonstrate your problem in less than 34 lines of code. In fact, I think it would be possible to demonstrate it in 3-4 lines.

Answer (score 1):

You use `Gramulator.for(@amount, @unit)`, but `Gramulator.for` expects `unit, amount`.

This causes `@units[unit]` to return nil, because you're giving it `"3.5"` instead of `"cups"` in the unit argument.

Comment: Yes, a bit of debug printing would have revealed this in a second.

Comment: No problem, all, I'm clearly new. I'll look into how to debug print now and thank you for the (mostly sarcasm free) help.

Comment: @Benjamin: yes, debugging is the most useful skill there is. Read [this](https://tenderlovemaking.com/2016/02/05/i-am-a-puts-debuggerer.html) for some inspiration/ideas.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `@units[unit]` you get `nil` because above it you're calling the `for` with **unit** and **amount** inverted. See `Gramulator.for(@amount, @unit)`. The signutre is `def self.for(unit, amount)`.

That being said...
Maybe I'm oversimplifying it, but I think your code could be reduced.

Below I rewrote it as a script which could be set as an executable (with `chmod +x`) and run as **./gramulator.rb**.

Feel free to skip the first and the last two lines if you need to incorporate this in a bigger project.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class Gramulator
  UNITS = { "cups" => 236.58 }

  def self.for(unit, amount)
    amount.to_f * UNITS[unit]
  end
end

class Recipe
  def initialize(ingredients)
    @ingredients = ingredients
  end

  def gramulate
    puts "CONVERTED TO GRAMS"
    @ingredients.each do |name, quantity|
      amount, unit = quantity.split
      puts "%s: %.2f grams" % [name, amount]
      Gramulator.for(unit, amount)
    end
  end
end

dough = Recipe.new({ bread_flour: "3.5 cups" })
dough.gramulate
```

Please **note** that `puts` returns `nil` and therefore is a good habit to avoid using it at the end of a loop/iteration ore method. Here you're using `each`, which is fine, because you're probably not interested in reusing the `ingredients.each {...}` result.

However, in Ruby, you could have a lot more fun with other useful `Enumerable` methods, such as **map**, **detect** etc. They return something different than the original collection you're iterating on so the last line of their loops needs to be 'something'. I strongly encourage you to look into them.

Sorry for being long, it's just to help you *feel* what Ruby can offer to you.

Comment: Thank you, and I agree wholeheartedly. But ironically I'm showing someone else how to DRY out a very long case statement with the factory. I'd prefer to leave the rest intact :)

Comment: uhm i'm trying to dry somthing which is already dry...Maybe i need a **cup** of 236.58ml  of **water** :)